# Android ellipse orbit animation

Tags: android, animation

I am using this for orbit a view in ellipse path but my problem is when view arrives in the middle there is a little slow down !

```
public class morbit extends Animation {

    @Override
    public boolean willChangeBounds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {

        float degg = interpolatedTime * 360;
        float angleDeg = (degg) % 360;
        double sino = Math.sin(degg * Math.PI / -180);
        sino= Math.abs(sino);
        double coso = Math.cos(degg * Math.PI / -180);
        coso= Math.abs(coso);

        double rrr = 40 + (sino * 150);

        float angleRad = (float) Math.toRadians(angleDeg);
        angleRad = angleRad;

        float y = (float) (40 * Math.cos(angleRad));
        float x = (float) (rrr * Math.sin(angleRad));

        t.getMatrix().setTranslate((float)x, (float)y);    
    }
}
```

.
.
.

```
morbit an = new morbit();
an.setDuration(6000);
an.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);
an.setRepeatCount(9999);
an.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dottx)).startAnimation(an);
```

I used `LinearInterpolator` but it's not helped me.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you aren't still stuck on this but for anyone else, try swapping:

sino and coso for

```
double sino =Math.sin(Math.PI + 200);

double coso = Math.cos(Math.PI + 400);
```

and swap rrr for

```
double rrr = 40 + (sino * 250);
```

I'm just working on this now myself so I'm not quite sure what the interpolatedTime was for although I'm guessing it makes sure the animation is spread evenly.  I don't seem to be having any problems without it though so maybe that was the problem.